# AngularJS bug in IE with style vs ng-style

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I'm using Angular JS v1.1.5, and found an interesting IE-related issue.

In IE 9, 10, 11 and Edge, the following does not seem to work, even though it works fine in Chrome:

```
<div style="width: {{progress.percent()}}%;"></div>
```

Whereas this works in all browsers:

```
<div ng-style="{width: progress.percent() + '%'}"></div>
```

I'm curious *why* the first option doesn't work in IE/Edge. Are there any known bugs around this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When IE 9 & 10 tries to render that HTML, it basically removes the invalid HTML found on HTML to be parse.

So having `style="display: {{'block'}}"` consider as invalid html, because it has unknown `{{}}` syntax & it make that attribute rendered as `style=""`

---

Other than having `ng-style` there you could use `ng-attr-*` directive like below

```
<div ng-attr-style="{{'width: '+ progress.percent() +'%;'}}"></div>
```

which will create style attribute when `progress.percent()` value does changed.

For more information look at this old logged [**github issue**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2186)

[**How style attribute become ""?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28939207/2435473)

Comment: This method of using ng-attr-style with string concatenation saved my butt in IE11. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

the problem also happens on edge. just write like this

```
[ngStyle]="{'width.px': 20}"
```