# Display a string as prettified HTML source code

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, prettify

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC web application.

On one page, I have a string that looks as follows:

```
<p>
    <i>This</i> is some <strong>text</strong>&nbsp;!
</p>
```

For preview mode, I use `Html.Raw(Model.MyText)`, and the text is displayed as rendered HTML:

> *This* is some **text** !

I want to now add a button to allow users to view the actual source of this text. I would like the button to open a new tab that displays the HTML text, formatted in a way that is readable, with proper line breaks and indentation.

#### Idea 1:

Based off the ideas I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1815227/4660897), my first though was to try to open the  `view-source` mode of a URL, with a link similar to the following:

```
<a target="_blank" href="view-source:http://www.example.com/">View source</a>
```

This would render the text exactly how I would like it to render:

> [image: view-source]

However, as of [this Bugzilla fix](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1172165), access to `view-source` URLs is denied.

#### Idea 2:

My next attempt was to get the `innerHTML`, and write that text to a new window:

```
function showSource(){
    source += document.getElementById('myDivID').innerHTML;
    source = source.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
    source = "<pre>" + source + "</pre>";
    sourceWindow = window.open('', '_blank');
    sourceWindow.document.write(source);
    sourceWindow.document.close();
    if(window.focus) sourceWindow.focus();
}
```

The method successfully passes the text over to a new tab, however, the code is displayed in a single, unformatted line that is not readable:

> `<p><i>This</i> is some <strong>text</strong>&nbsp;!</p>`

#### Idea 3:

I also thought of just removing the `Html.Raw()`, however this idea also renders the code in an unreadable format:

> `<p><i>This</i> is some <strong>text</strong>&nbsp;!</p>`

How can I get `Model.MyText` string to open in a new tab and render as prettified HTML?

Ideally, it would be great if this can be accomplished with just HTML or JavaScript, but I'm open to ideas that would require a call to an MVC ActionResult as well.

Comment: would you be ok with using js code editors like [ace](https://ace.c9.io/) or [code mirror](https://codemirror.net/)

Comment: Using a code editor seems to be overkill for what I am trying to do. Also, I'm not looking to edit the text. For this button, I'm just looking for a way to render a quick and clean code preview.

Comment: have you solved this in some way? @Tot

Comment: @alex No, I am still looking for a solution that won't require a whole editor. Thank you for your idea though.