# JS - Function for showing the Source of a WebPage

Tags: javascript, html, browser

We use AngularJS to override the Browser Context Menu (https://github.com/Templarian/ui.bootstrap.contextMenu).

Here is the some example code

```
$scope.menuOptions = [
{
    text: \'Cut\',
    click: function () {
        alert(\'Cut\');
    }   
},
{
    text: \'Copy\',
    click: function () {
        alert(\'Copy\');
    }   
},
{
    text: \'Pase\',
    click: function () {
        alert(\'Paste\');
    }   
}
' . $showDebugMenu . ' 
];
```

The showDebugMenu var gets a further function to show the source code of the website if the setting in the database is set to on.

My question: Is there a function to show the source code or to call the browser to show source code function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically open "View Source" HTML Window in Browser with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815021/programmatically-open-view-source-html-window-in-browser-with-javascript)